# Generating a Map[String, List[String]] from List[(String,String)]

Tags: scala, dictionary

I got the following list of pairs:

```
 List(("US","New York"),("England","London"),("US","Los Angeles"),("England","Manchester"),("US","Washington"))
```

I need to generate a `Map[Country, List[Cities]]`:

```
Map("US" -> List("New York", "Los Angeles", "Washington"), "England" -> List("London", "Manchester"))
```

The problem that if I use `toMap()` directly the values with same keys are removed.

The story so far:

```
list.groupBy(el => el).map(el => el._1 -> ?)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using groupBy:

```
list.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
```

using fold:

```
list.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, List[String]]) { case (m, (k, v)) =>
  m.updated(k, v :: m.getOrElse(k, List()))
}
```